# How to get pretty output from specs+scalacheck with maven?

Tags: scala, maven, specs, scalacheck

When I run Specs + Scalacheck tests with IDEA, I get nice pretty output:

```
  Specification "CoreSpec"
    The core grammar should
    + parse any encoded string
    + fail to parse an empty encoded string
    + parse an expected empty string
    + fail on a non-empty string when expecting an empty string
    + parse well-formed coordinates
```

In order to get my tests to run with maven, I have the usual:

```
class CoreSpecTest extends JUnit4(CoreSpec)
```

...but then the output is not very satisfying:

```
Running CoreSpecTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.782 sec

Results :

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Is there a way to get the pretty output in this case?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some workaround for my project:

f.e. I have specs

class SomeSpec extends HtmlSpecification with Textile  {
....
}

class Some2Spec extends HtmlSpecification with Textile  {
....
}

also I have Junit test like this

@Test
class AppTest {

```
@Test
def testOk = {}

@Test
def printSpecs  {
    (new SomeSpec).reportSpecs
    (new Some2Spec).reportSpecs
}
```

}

I know that this is not good solution, so
I think that the best is to migrate from maven to sbt.